# How to make one volume with maximal capacity out of the two disks in a 2-bay NAS without striping

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology, raid0

I have a Synology NAS with two disks which I want to combine to one large volume for backing up an other system.

I don't need redundancy, so something like RAID 0 would do. However I don't need the speed benefit of striping the data, but rather use the disks somehow *one after the other*, so that when one disks fails the data on the other is still readable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up drives as concatenated, you will still lose access to data if one drive fails.

This happens because file system metadata (allocation table etc.) is on one disk, and without metadata you cannot know where files are on the disk.

Comment: Thanks @Tero. I was fearing this. I just hoped there would be a way that both drives *share a mirrored TOC*, but the *data is always on only one drive*…

Comment: Technically that could be possible, but I am not aware of any file system that would work like this.